# Meteor upgrade to 1.0.3.1 now I get ReferenceError: moment is not defined

Tags: meteor, momentjs

After upgrading to Meteor 1.0.3.1 I now get this error

```
ReferenceError: moment is not defined
```

I can see here that it upgraded the momentjs to a newer version

```
momentjs:moment                  added, version 2.8.4
mrt:moment                       removed from your project
tsega:bootstrap3-datetimepicker  upgraded from 3.1.3_1 to 3.1.3_3
```

Here is the code from the first place that I get that error

```
var today = new moment().format('MM/DD/YYYY');
```

Seems like it should still work. I tried to reinstall it and now the app is crashing.

Has anybody else had this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the moment package on Atmosphere is actually up to 2.9.0. Try either running a meteor update, or manually remove the moment package (meteor remove momentjs:moment) and re-adding it.

Also, you shouldn't need to use new moment(), just moment(), like this:

```
var today = moment().format('MM/DD/YYYY');
```

Comment: Running the meteor update again made things worse for some reason. Removing and then adding back moment from the project directory did the trick. Thanks!